# How can I get all photos in PhotoStream on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photo-stream

I recently had to completely reset my iPhone, and now the only photos present in PhotoStream on my phone are the ones that have been added to my PhotoStream account after the reset. How can I force my phone to re-sync all the previous photos as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is an answer, but I wanted to add some images, so:

First, what computer / os do you use? Can you see the photos on this computer? If you are using iPhoto or Aperture and the photos you are looking for are not visible in these programs, they have already been removed from the iCloud server and cannot be re-synced to iPhone (at least not through Photo Stream). iCloud only stores the last 30 days worth, or 1000 photos, whichever limit is hit first.

On the iPhone, go to Settings then iCloud (as seen in the first image below).
Next, tap on Photo Stream, and ensure the "My Photo Stream" slider is set to ON (as seen in the second image below).

[image]
[image]

Finally, (as this is iCloud (grrrh), it might help to turn these settings off, wait a few hours, and turn them on again. I had to do this recently, with photos and mail. Hope this helps.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was the "turning the settings off, waiting, then turning them on again" that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make some coffee and get ready for longer process; Make sure your iPhone is in WiFi range, as it will need to download missing pictures from Streaming.
2. On your iPhone, go to your Photos and empty Camera Roll folder (that is optional, but makes things more clear);
3. Make sure you have some reasonable space left on your iPhone (~1Gb);
4. In your iPhone's Photos, tap on Streaming, then tap on Edit (pic 1);
5. Select all photos needed to be extracted (pic 2);
6. Tap on Share and then tap on Save to Camera Roll (pic 3);

All selected photos will be downloaded from Streaming back to your Camera Roll (pic 4). Once it is done, your photos will be accessible from iPhotos or ImageCapture or other apps like iFunBox or else.

[image: Go to Streaming]

[image: Select Photos]

[image: Tap on Share, tap on Save to Camera Roll]

[image: Wait until is downloaded all]

Comment: **A very important note:** after doing that, your pictures in Streaming library might be fed with duplicates. This depends _(I'm presuming only, by noticing how it acts)_ on proper sync between Camera Roll and Streaming, as it holds old pictures for much longer than 30 days (the last pics I recovered from Streaming were 8 months old)

Comment: This answer seems to be about getting photos back into Camera Roll. My question was regarding the full past history syncing of My Photo Stream photos on a reset phone.

Comment: Just red your question few times again. Surely, I have misunderstand the way you needed to sync it (sorry about that), and by your response to the first post, seems it solved? As well, by this topic title: **How can I get all photos in PhotoStream on my iPhone?** seems my answer finds the right place to be held in here, I suppose.